# Testing paginated UIScrollView on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios4, automated-tests

I'm creating a magazine reader (something like iGizmo on iPad). I have two scrollviews one that paginate over articles and second to paginate inside of an article through pages.

I'd like to check memory usage of my app after scrolling through 20 pages.
To do so I decided to create an automated ui test that scrolls 20 times right and the  check the memory foot print at the end of the test.

I need that info to have some metrics before I start optimizing the memory usage

And Here is the thing: I can't make the ui automation to pass to the second page. My automation code looks like that:

```
var window = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow(); 
var articleScrollView = window.scrollViews()[0]; 
articleScrollView.scrollRight(); 
// do you know any command to wait until first scrolls ends?
articleScrollView.scrollRight(); // this one doesn't work
```

I guess that I need to wait for the first scorlling to end before I can run another one, but I don't know how to do that as each page is just an image. (I don't have anything else on pages yet)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

try inserting a delay of 1 or 2 seconds between the consecutive scrolls.

This works for me. Hope it does for you too.

var window = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow(); 
**target = UIATarget.localTarget();**
var articleScrollView = window.scrollViews()[0];
**target.delay(1);** //delay of 1 second 
articleScrollView.scrollRight(); 
// do you know any command to wait until first scrolls ends?
**target.delay(1);** //delay of 1 second 
articleScrollView.scrollRight(); // this one doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to delay the command execution. I will have a look tomorrow.